# Searching SSIS packages for the use of specific tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a number of SSIS packages, how can I search them to find the use of specific tables? I need to make tables changes and I am trying to assess the impact of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSIS code behind is actually a XML value and all components of package will be represented as XML node values within it.This XML can be parsed to identify if it has a reference for our searched table or column.

[Finding SSIS Packages having References to a Table or Column](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26784.finding-ssis-packages-having-references-to-a-table-or-column.aspx) will help you.

Comment: You can also use a text crawler or a Powershell Script to comb through your source control directory.

Comment: this will not give you everything, if variables are being used you will miss things as you cannot say with 100% certainty what is being used

Answer (score 2):

I was looking  for a similar solution, to find references of a table in all the SSIS packages I have.

The solution that worked for me was simple, I copied all the SSIS packages that needed to be searched to a folder and used the 'Find in Files' function from notepad++ wherein you can provide the search string and the path to this folder.

It works on the basis that dtsx can be edited as xml on notepad++. I am sure there are other solutions. Hope it helps.

Comment: For me, too:  I used Notepad++.  People sometimes forget that SSIS packages are XML, and Notepad++ makes XML easy to understand.  Of course that means that the SSIS package must be a windows file, rather than stored in msdb (package deployment model) or SSISDB (project deployment model).  In my case, I didn't know the full filename, but knew enough that the "find" feature gave me the tablenames within nodes (for example, table references within source or destination components within dataflow tasks), *and* the tablename references within SQL scripts (within Execute SQL tasks).